# Is it possible to have a theme that uses only one single page?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I'm working on a specialized site design and I'd like to know if it's possible to have a theme made out of one single php page. I seem to recall that it was possible but there were some issues with it.

I'm trying to make it as simple as possible so I would like to exclude answers based on child themes. I don't want any extra CSS, JS or HTML.

Comment: please add more explanation, are you looking for single page theme? or want to make a single page template?

Answer (score 2):

You could code it all in the `index.php` file in your theme folder.

Just write all the code in the file. Be sure to call the functions like `wp_head()` etc.